# Does valgrind detect OpenGL memory leaks?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am testing an OpenGL application and I am purposely not deleting a lot of OpenGL constructs to check for memory leaks.

For example I created an array of multiple shaders and never called `glDeleteShader()`

However valgrind reports no memory leaks,

Is it that valgrind is unable to detect these memory leaks, or is it that there is some garbage collector going behind my back ensuring no such leaks happen?

Comment: The shaders, IIRC, exist on your graphics hardware or display server. valgrind can only detect memory leaks in your process. If your process sends opengl commands to create five shaders, and in the process of doing so it frees all memory that it used to do so, as far as the process is concerned all process memory has been freed, and your process does not leak memory.

Comment: What happens to the data in the GPU RAM then? If I don't explicetly call the glDeleteX() functions, is this equivalent to a memory leak in the GPU?

Comment: @Makogen Yes probably, in the GPU and/or in the driver. The point is Valgrind can't detect it.

Comment: Is there a program that would allow me to check for memory leaks in the GPU?

Comment: Without knowing the inner working of the OpenGL library, it is highly likely that a file descriptor gets used to talk to the graphics card, via the kernel, and when the file descriptor gets closed, the kernel informs the graphics card to release all resources associated with it. This should be very easy to test. Write a simple program to create, but not free the shaders. Write a simple script to repeatedly execute it. If the shader resources don't get cleaned up it shouldn't take long for the card to run out of memory, and refuse to create any more shaders.

Comment: You might get some information from CodeXL. NSight might also provide some data.

Comment: The driver has no idea you aren't going to use those objects again unless you explicitly tell it.  I'm not a driver writer but I'm pretty sure that's context-local state that should go away when you delete the context or if you don't do that, when the OS terminates your process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However valgrind reports no memory leaks

That is because the default configuration of Valgrind blacklists OpenGL from being profiled. This is for a simple reason: Most OpenGL implementations do garbage collect their objects. When you do a call to `glDelete…` then all what happens is, that the "externally" accessible object names/IDs are being disassociated from the actual internal representations.

The OpenGL implementation may have to hold on to the actual data for much longer after the `glDelete…` call; for example there might still be rendering commands in flight that reference objects with names which have been "deleted". The actual cleanup usually happens much later than "your" call of `glDelete…`. Also most OpenGL implementations will not actually deallocate memory, but keep it around for recycling with newly created names.

The bottom line is, that with a typical OpenGL implementation Valgrind would report a lot of memory leaks, even if everything is cleanly tidied up on program termination. Hence it's blacklisted.

Comment: Then, memory wise, it's ok to not explicetly delete those constructs at the end of my application? Is this a good practice?

Comment: @Makogan: Actually, if you know for certain that the process is about to terminate, it's perfectly okay not to deallocate anything. Just make sure, that all data writes (leaving the process) have been flushed and synced (to prevent loss of data). But other than that, just terminate the process. Going around, deallocating everything, going through each and every destructor is like giving a house a do-over and paint job right before the demolishion crew goes to work with explosives and a wrecking ball. In fact, it might cause unneccesary delay, forcing the OS to page in swapped out memory.

Comment: @Makogan: Just to make this clear: When a process terminates, the operating system (which includes graphics drivers) makes sure, that anything the process did allocate becomes available again. Actually, what the OS does is, that it simply discards the information that there had been an allocation at all. All the used resources reappear to be available almost instantly.